# create txt file in selected location in c# application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a c# application. In this Form I have added 2 buttons.
Those are `Browse` and `Create File` Buttons.

Now I want to do is use browse button to browse a location and when click `Create file` button, create a text file in that location.

Comment: Is it winforms or wpf?

Comment: Are you sure you want two buttons? It's rare for an application to have separate "set file location" and "save" actions.

Comment: @wudzik - its windows forms

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever- yes,because using browse button, I want to select the location only. And using "Create file" button it will create a text file in selected location.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at

[SaveFileDialog Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx)

> Prompts the user to select a location for saving a file.

or

[FolderBrowserDialog Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx)

> Prompts the user to select a folder.

[File.Create Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.create.aspx)

> Creates a file in the specified path.

or even

[File.CreateText Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext.aspx)

> Creates or opens a file for writing UTF-8 encoded text

Comment: I have tried SaveFileDialog. But I cannot select a folder location. When browsing, It asks a file to select the location.

Comment: @amila - then you want [`FolderBrowserDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx) then.

Answer (score 2):

on click event do it like this

```
//if you want to overwrite the file if it already exists you can bypass this check
if (File.Exists(path))
{               
      File.Delete(path);
}

        // Create the file. 
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
        {
            Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("This is some text in the file.");
            // Add some information to the file.
            fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
        }
```

if you don't intend to write anything

```
FileStream fs = File.Create(path);
fs.Close();  //this needs to be done
```

You need to read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03.aspx).

Comment: File delete won't throw an error if the file doesnt exist, no need to check it

Comment: what if users wants to create a new file instead of overwriting it?

Comment: I'm not saying don't use delete, I'm saying that delete does nothing if the file isn't there

Comment: this is the reason that there is a check if file exists then delete it

Comment: I personally prefer [`File.WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext.aspx) or [`File.AppendAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendalltext.aspx) - both take care of creating/opening, writing to, and closing the file. The former overwrites, while the latter appends to, the file. Handy for writing text to a file. There is [`File.WriteAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx) as well.

Comment: But my problem is how to get the selected path?

Comment: private void  folderBrowserDialog1_HelpRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             string filepath = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
             
            textBox1.Text = filepath;
        }     -----------------------------------------------------is this correct or?